# react-scripts : compilation error while importing SVG

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-script to build my app. I have this error:

```
SyntaxError: unknown: Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can set `throwIfNamespace: false` to bypass this warning.
```

But where to specify this option [throwIfNamespace] ? in package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

The `throwIfNamespace` option is a `@babel/preset-react` option
see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react#usage

The configuration can be in your `.babelrc` or `package.json` file as follows:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "throwIfNamespace": false // defaults to true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not working. I tried in a `.babelrc` in `package.json` :

```
{
   "babel": {
      "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        {
          "throwIfNamespace": false
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

any other solution ?